# Moq to set up a function return based on called times

Tags: c#, moq

I need to mock an interface to call to MSMQ, is there a way I can use Moq to simulate real MSMQ scenario that there are 10 messages in the queue, I call mocked function 10 times and I can get a pre-defined object, on 11th time I should get a different return value (e.g. null)?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Moq now has an **extension method** called `SetupSequence()` in the `Moq` namespace which means you can define a distinct return value for each specific call.

The general idea is that that you just chain the return values you need.
In the example bellow the first call will return **Joe** and the second call will return **Jane**:

```
customerService
.SetupSequence(s => s.GetCustomerName(It.IsAny<int>()))
.Returns("Joe")   //first call
.Returns("Jane"); //second call
```

Some more info [here](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/define-different-return-values-in-moq).

Comment: It looks like the link is irrelevant :/

Answer (score 17):

I sometimes use a simple counter for such scenarios:

```
int callCounter = 0;
var mock = new Mock<IWhatever>();
mock.Setup(a => a.SomeMethod())
    .Returns(() => 
    {
       if (callCounter++ < 10)
       {
           // do something
       }
       else
       {
           // do something else
       }
    });
```

Comment: Good solution. It is also possible to append `.CallBack( ... )` where the ellipsis represents delegate that modifies `callCounter` and possibly other state.

Comment: This is a very brilliant idea indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set up a separate function to do this. You can even pass the function a parameter if you want:

```
_serviceMock.Setup(x => x.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<String>())).Returns((String param) => getTimesCalled(param));
```